# Programa batalha naval c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho que fazer um jogo de batalha naval pra faculdade utilizando windows forms no visual studio, o problema e que nao consegui entender a logica para gerar mapas de batalha naval, nao consigo pensar numa maneira de fazer isso.

O que deve ser feito é colocar barcos personalizados, alem dos que já tem, que são: Um porta-aviões(cinco quadrados cada), Dois tanques(quatro quadrados cada), Três torpedeiros (três quadrados cada), Quatro submarinos (dois quadrados cada).

O jogador também entra com o tamanho do mapa, com isso é gerado 2 mapas, um para o player 1 e um para o player 2. Quando o player 1 entra com todos os navios, eles se escondem e ai ficam `disabled`, entao o player 2 pode colocar seus navios e eles se escondem e ai trocam os mapas para poder começar o jogo.

Me falaram pra usar `picturebox[,]` mas como isso funciona? aAlguem ja fez algo parecido?

Tenho que salvar o ranking em arquivo mas eu tenho ideia de como fazer isso.
Fiz um codigo aqui para menu vou deixar aqui.

Classe Jogador:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BatalhaNaval
{
    class Jogador
    {
        private string nome;
        private int pontos;
        public Jogador()
        {

        }
        public int Pontos
        {
            get
            {
                return pontos;
            }
            set
            {
                pontos = value;
            }
        }
        public string Nome
        {
            get
            {
                return nome;
            }
            set
            {
                nome = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Codigo do Menu

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BatalhaNaval
{
    public partial class menu : Form
    {
        public menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Formulario janelanome = new Formulario();
            janelanome.Show();
            Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Formulario do nome do jogador e tamanho do mapa

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BatalhaNaval
{
    public partial class Formulario : Form
    {
        public Formulario()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            jogo janelajogo = new BatalhaNaval.jogo();
            janelajogo.Show();
            Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Print do menu:

[image: Menu]

Print do form:

[image: Formulario]

Comment: Consegui fazer um picture box personalizado mas como eu vou trabalhar com ele para armazenar os navios, e como vou colocar os navios nos 2 tabuleiros?

Comment: Você já conseguiu avançar no seu projeto?

Comment: Dica para a vida: separe a lógica do jogo da sua representação em tela. Faça o jogo todo sem pensar em tela, depois você pensa em quais componentes de tela vai usar.

Comment: eu estou fazendo por picture box o problema e que sao 7x7 a 15x15 o tamanho do tabuleiro que pode ser escolhido, e para colocar os navios esta sendo dificil pois estou fazendo if por if nao sei se existe uma maneira mais eficiente de fazer isso

Answer (score 1):

Então, você pode fazer isso de N formas diferentes... Pode existir maneira mais fácil, mas eu faria em uma [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx), utilizando Linhas e Colunas pra fazer o mapa.

Pra preencher o mapa com os devidos navios, você pode criar botões que definem quantos quadrados você pode ocupar. Por exemplo, ao clicar no botão TORPEDEIRO, você define que só podem ser efetuados 3 cliques (através de um contador).

Você também deverá verificar se a célula da DataGridView já foi preenchida, pra verificar os acertos dos jogadores (pra afundar os navios ou contar quantos faltam para serem). Será necessário também linkar as respectivas células para cada navio adicionado, pra avisar se foi atingido ou já foi afundado, por exemplo:

```
COLUNA/LINHA       NAVIO 
     A2         DESTROIER_1
     A3         DESTROIER_1
     A4         DESTROIER_1
     C4         DESTROIER_2
     D4         DESTROIER_2
     E4         DESTROIER_2
```

Novamente, existe N formas de você fazer isso.

edit1: respondendo a pergunta do @Arthur

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você clicou aqui (1), você tem que verificar se os cliques podem ser nos itens de vermelho,e para isso, você pode utilizar a matemática como aliada para realizar as verificações. Novamente, talvez essa não seja a melhor forma de fazer isso, mas é uma abordagem que eu provavelmente faria.

Comment: usando contador como eu poderia tratar um erro se ele colocasse na diagonal o navio ou colocasse em lugar diferentes do permitido?

Comment: Bom, se você parar pra pensar, é um pouco chatinho de fazer. Tipo, primeiro você tem de definir o que é proibido, se você clicou em um ponto, você tem que verificar se o próximo ponto clicado é de acordo com os requisitos.
Olhe o editado.

Comment: estou pensando numa maneira aqui obrigado